# Boolean is being initialised as true, even though the constructor is passed false

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, oop

Interesting issue with my code... running in debug mode (Eclipse/CDT)... all of my tiles seem to have their wall bool set to true? Anyone know wtf is going on?

Code, fully MVC and almost proper OO (I think), here:

main.cpp http://pastebin.com/f14kmfap

gridworld.h http://pastebin.com/vCmzxzrj

gridworld.cpp http://pastebin.com/jKKRFE9V

I suspect it has to do with this snippet here:

```
Tile::Tile(bool w) {
        wall = w;
        event = false;
        eventText = "";
}
```

And how I use it to generate the map:

```
map[1][2] = new Tile(false);
```

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to dig through the pastebin to help you.  Make a small self-contained example of the problem and post that here.

Comment: Which tiles in particular are you expecting to be false? Also don't forget to clean up the memory for all your new Tile() statements.

Comment: @xdhmoore all of the tiles declared by lines 68 through 95. They all use the non-default constructors.

Comment: ummm? why cant you just run a debugger on it with the breakpoint on the ctors? or even print statements? You will find out easily enough

Comment: I'm having trouble finding anything. Is it possible your debugger is not running on the most recent version of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `Tile map[8][8];`, will have the tiles default constructed. with the bool `wall` set to true.

In the Map constructor you are using `Map::map[r][c] = new Tile()` the right hand side is a `Tile*`, the left hand side is a `Tile`. 
The proper syntax for *assigning to map* would be `map[r][c] = Tile();`, or `map[6][4]=Tile(false);`

Comment: Thanks! I just figured this out with the help of a friend. Exactly what I learnt! Thanks.

Comment: It will compile: the pointer is converted to `bool`, and then to `Tile` via the conversion constructor. So the allocated tile is silently leaked and ignored, and the one in the array is initialised with `true`. You can avoid errors like this by making conversion constructors explicit: `explicit Map(bool w)`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `new Tile()` in many places which uses default ctor of `Tile`. Inside default ctor of `Tile` you are initializing `wall = true;`.

Comment: This is true, but all of the calls to the overloaded Tile(bool w) seem to still set wall to true, where it is always passed as false, like in the example.